# Can't scrape some "div" tags from a site

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape job posts from this page: https://www.fl.ru.

Probably quite a newbie problem, but it turns out I can get certain tags, while others seem to be unreachable, e.g.:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://www.fl.ru/projects/")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

textTags = bsObj.findAll("div", class_="b-post__txt ")
print(str(textTags))
```

Thanks

Comment: which are unreachable? is it possible that some of the divs are generated via javascript (which `urllib` would miss)?

Comment: I don't see any elements on that page with the specified class. Try opening your browser's developer tools and running `document.querySelectorAll('.b-post__txt')`

Comment: hey you are using `class_` instead of `class` be catious

Comment: @HimanshuGahlot the selector for the `class` attribute of `.find_all()` is supposed to use `class_='className'` and is used correctly in this example.

Comment: @BenG-TW firstly check with this xpath `//div[@class="b-post__txt "]` on the page, Secondly he should use `bsObj.findAll("div", {'class':"b-post__txt "})` instead of `bsObj.findAll("div", class_="b-post__txt ")`. And lastly if this content needs to wait for some javascript then kindly use selenium with proper wait system. If need any further clarification ping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the page html using some downloader (`wget` or `curl`) you will see that the elements are not in the page at all. The elements are being generated by javascript.

For example (snippet from the source of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<div class="b-post__body b-post__body_padtop_15 b-post__body_overflow_hidden b-layuot_width_full"> <div class="b-post__txt "> У нас есть для вас вакансия Full-stack PHP-разработчика на удаленную работу (полный рабочий день) или в офис (г. Москва).&nbsp; Работать нужно будет над нашими проектами, в том... </div> <div id="project-reason-3728923" style="display: none"> </div> </div>');</script>
```

You have two options: Execute the javascript (with a browser and something like selenium to drive it) or parse it manually, by using beautiful soup to get the `<script>` tag contents, then extracting the text inside `document.write()` and reparsing it with beautiful soup.

Comment: @Ttheshirt Glad to hear that my solution helped you buddy!

Answer (score -1):

Many modern webpages build the DOM in the browser dynamically using Javascript, and the parts you're looking for do not exist until the browser has finished building the page.

If you're not using a browser or library that has Javascript functionality, the page elements you're looking for will simply not exist.